# How to compile a Firmware project by using command prompt

Tags: c, command-prompt, firmware

I am looking for a bunch of code lines to compile a firmware project by using command prompt. I found for compiling just a `.c` file it's enough to write `gcc -o filename.c`.
However my project is a folder with a number of `.c` files `.h` files and 3 other formats and I have no idea how to run and compile the whole folder by cmd.

Here is content of project:

[image: Here is the content of file:]

Would you give me some advice on what are related commands for this?

Thanks

Comment: `gcc -o filename.c` - Are you sure it is working for you?

Comment: is there any makefile ?

Comment: ^If there is none, you should consider one.

Comment: @farbiondriven  attached a photo

Comment: @ Eugene Sh Never tried that one. I need something for whole project not just a single file

Comment: Well there's a makefile.targets file.  Does it have anything in it, and does anything make use of it?

Comment: Write a `Makefile` that contains the necessary scrip to: 1) compile each of the source files into object files, 2) generate the dependency files and include them in the compile 3) link the object files into the final executable.  There are plenty of `Makefile` examples on stackoverflow.com and elsewhere on the web.  To assist you (although it is steep learning curve) you could read the `make` [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual)